# What is meant by taking dual of a boolean expression?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, sop

I read online that if we have a set of SOP terms giving a boolean expression, then the POS terms of the complement of the SOP terms will give the same expression.
POS(f)=SOP(f').

This is called taking the dual of the expression. How does this work?

If I have:
f = BD + AC + CE

Its complement:
f' = (B' + D')(A' + C')(C' + E')

What is meant by taking the dual of f, and how do we get f in POS form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dual of a boolean expression is an expression that is obtained following these steps:

- replace any logical sum (OR) with a logical product (AND)
- replace any logical product (AND) with a logical sum (OR)
- replace any 0 constant with a 1 constant
- replace any 1 constant with a 0 constant

The two basic logical operations AND and OR are called *dual* of each other, i.e. AND is the dual operation of OR and viceversa. Hence the dual transformation can be explained as:

***Replace any operation with its dual and any constant with its complement (negation).***

Note that negations must not be changed.

Comment: Huh?   
This appears to contradict itself.
"Replace .... any constant with its complement (negation)."
but 
"Note that negations must not be changed."  Can someone elaborate?

Comment: @nickalh Please, reread well. There's no contradiction: *constants* must be replaced with their negation, as explained above: 0 with 1 and 1 with 0, but negations (i.e. NOT operators) must not be touched.

Comment: still an example, probably 1 example with both literals and variables would clarify.